# trying to add a pager to carouFredSel slide show

Tags: jquery, slideshow, caroufredsel

I am trying to add a simple pagination to my carouFredSel slide show. I have almost got it working, but the opaque images on the left and right do not want to corporate. when I click the page button right the opaque img on the right will do nothing, when I click the page button left the left img will do nothing. I am so close I can taste victory.

What I attempted to do was add: 
    pagination: "#page2",
 to line 26. it kinda worked but not totally.

[My jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/moLLay38/2/)

```
$(function() {
    var $l = $('#carousel-left'),
        $c = $('#carousel-center'),
        $r = $('#carousel-right');

    $l.carouFredSel({
        auto: false,
        items: 1,
        direction: 'right',
        prev: {
            button: '#prev',
            fx: 'fade', // left side when prev is clicked
            onBefore: function() {
                setTimeout(function() {
                    $c.trigger( 'prev' );
                }, 1);
            }   
        },
        next: {
            fx: 'fade' //right side when next is clicked
        }
    });
    $c.carouFredSel({
        auto: false,
        items: 1,
        pagination: "#page2",
        prev: {
            onBefore: function() {
                setTimeout(function() {
                    $r.trigger( 'prev' );
                }, 1); //effected only on previous button click
            }
        },
        next: {
            onBefore: function() {
                setTimeout(function() {
                    $l.trigger( 'next' );
                }, 1); // effects left side
            }
        }
    });
    $r.carouFredSel({
        auto: false,
        items: 1,
        prev: {
            fx: 'fade' //right side when prev is clicked
        },
        next: {
            button: '#next',
            fx: 'fade', //right side when next button is clicked
            onBefore: function() {
                setTimeout(function() {
                    $c.trigger( 'next' );
                }, 1); //delay for center img
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

After looking at your JSFiddle, your navigation arrows seem to be working as they are intended to. Moving one slide at a time to the left or right.

Also your coloured pagination at the bottom also seems to be functioning properly.

Is your issue maybe browser related? As in Google Chrome it seems to be performing as expected..